# openssh module in iron python from windows to linux to run commands

Tags: python, windows, ssh, ironpython, openssh

I am using openssh in iron python to run commands from windows to linux. I have installed openssh in both the machines and the service is running. I have added keys in authorized users even

```
conn = SSHConnection(ip_addr, login=name)
ret = conn.run('ls')
or 
ret = conn.run(['ls'])
```

I am getting error as follows

```
"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\openssh_wrapper.py", line 164, in run
"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\subprocess.py", line 675, in __init__
"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\subprocess.py", line 887, in _execute_child
Error: [Errno 2] The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What is wrong in the code?

Comment: what is in subprocess.py line 887?

Answer (score 0):

The line in my copy is

```
ssh_command = self.ssh_command(interpreter, forward_ssh_agent)
```

where interpreter, if not specified, defaults to `/bin/bash`.  I think it's saying it doesn't see /bin/bash on the remote machine.